# Showing, Hiding Images based on Radio Button Selection

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a sort-of interactive image that changes based on radio button selection.

I have all the images layered at the same position and size and I want one layer in a section to be visible when selected while the rest are hidden. This is meant to showcase what your combination of choices will look like. I'm trying to do this with just HTML and CSS and feel close but do not know why it isn't working.

Currently, the code is set up to experiment with just the leather option.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <style type="text/css">


    label {
        font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
    }

    #baseLayer {
        background-image: url(baseLayer.png);
        width: 100%;

    }

    #choices div {
        float: left;
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .outerWrapper {
        position: relative;
    }

    .layer {
        position: absolute;
    }

    input#leather1:checked ~ #l1 {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    input#leather2:checked ~ #l2 {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    input#leather1:not(:checked) ~ #l1 {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    input#leather2:not(:checked) ~ #l2 {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

</style>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Interactivity</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="baseLayer" class="outerWrapper">
    <img id="c1" class="layer" src="counter1.png">
    <img id="c2" class="layer" src="counter2.png">
    <img id="f1" class="layer" src="floor1.png">
    <img id="f2" class="layer" src="floor2.png">
    <img id="l1" class="layer" src="leather1.png">
    <img id="l2" class="layer" src="leather2.png">
    <img id="u1" class="layer" src="upholstery1.png">
    <img id="u2" class="layer" src="upholstery2.png">
    <img id="u3" class="layer" src="upholstery3.png">
</div>

<div id="choices">

<div>
      Upholstery:<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="u" id="upholstery1" value="Black">
      <label for="upholstery1">1</label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="u" id="upholstery2" value="blue">
      <label for="upholstery2">2</label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="u" id="upholstery3" value="green">
      <label for="upholstery3">3</label><br>
</div>

<div>
      Leather:<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="l" id="leather1" value="black_leather">
      <label> Black</label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="l" id="leather2" value="brown_leather">
      <label> Brown</label><br>
</div>

<div>
      Floor Cover:<br/>
      <label> 1
      <input type="radio" name="f" value="orange"></label><br>
      <label> 2
      <input type="radio" name="f" value="yellow"></label><br>
</div>

<div>
      Countertop:<br/>
      <label> 1
      <input type="radio" name="c" value="pink"></label><br>
      <label> 2
      <input type="radio" name="c" value="teal"></label><br>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your radio inputs and images are in different divs, so they cannot access each other. For the radio selected to affect the img shown, it would have to go up to the `<div` and back down the `#baseLayer`. You can't travel up the DOM tree with css. You will need to add in some javascript. Here's an example below.

**Edit:**
Added some comments to the javascript/jquery so you can understand what I did to be able to replicate it for what you need.

```js
$('#choices input').on('change',function(){
  //Getting the content of the label that is right after the input.
  var numb = $(this).next().html();
  
  //Hiding all the with an id that containes the input's name.
  $("img[id*='"+this.name+"']").hide();
  
  //Using the name of the input element and adding the content of the label to it, showing the image with that id.
  $('#'+this.name+numb).show();
    
  });
```

```css
label {
        font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
    }

    #baseLayer {
        background-color:peachpuff;
        width: 100%;
        padding:15px;
        display:table;
    }
    #choices{
      display:table;
      width:100%;
    }
    #choices div {
        float: left;
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .column-half{
      float:left;
      width:50%;
      position:relative;
    }
    .outerWrapper {
        position: relative;
    }

    .layer {
        display:block;
    }

    input#leather1:checked ~ #l1 {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    input#leather2:checked ~ #l2 {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    input#leather1:not(:checked) ~ #l1 {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    input#leather2:not(:checked) ~ #l2 {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
  .layer{
    display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <style type="text/css">


    
</style>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Interactivity</title>
</head>

<body>
      <div id="choices">

            <div>
                  Upholstery:<br/>
                  <input type="radio" name="u" id="upholstery1" value="Black">
                  <label for="upholstery1">1</label><br>
                  <input type="radio" name="u" id="upholstery2" value="blue">
                  <label for="upholstery2">2</label><br>
                  <input type="radio" name="u" id="upholstery3" value="green">
                  <label for="upholstery3">3</label><br>
            </div>

            <div>
                  Leather:<br/>
                  <input type="radio" name="l" id="leather1" value="black_leather">
                  <label>1</label><br>
                  <input type="radio" name="l" id="leather2" value="brown_leather">
                  <label>2</label><br>
            </div>

            <div>
                  Floor Cover:<br/>

                  <input type="radio" name="f" value="orange">
                  <label>1</label><br>
                  <input type="radio" name="f" value="yellow">
                  <label>2</label><br>
            </div>

            <div>
                  Countertop:<br/>

                  <input type="radio" name="c" value="pink">
                  <label>1</label><br>      
                  <input type="radio" name="c" value="teal">
                  <label>2</label><br>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div id="baseLayer" class="outerWrapper">
          <div class="column-half">
              <img id="c1" class="layer" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/100/200">
              <img id="c2" class="layer" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/150/200">
          </div>
          <div class="column-half">
              <img id="f1" class="layer" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/200/200">
              <img id="f2" class="layer" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/250/200">
          </div>
          <div class="column-half">
              <img id="l1" class="layer" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/300/200">
              <img id="l2" class="layer" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/350/200">
          </div>
          <div class="column-half">
              <img id="u1" class="layer" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/400/200">
              <img id="u2" class="layer" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/450/200">
              <img id="u3" class="layer" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/500/200">
          </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is great! The Murray was a nice touch. However, this code does not seem to be working quite how I want it. I want the other layers to change in accordance to the click. I have a bunch of images that are transparent and need all four varieties of images to be visible.

In your case of the Bill Murray's. If you selected one item from each section there should be four images present. But now, it only is working for the 'upholstery' section and when I click another button in a different section everything gets hidden until I click another choice in upholstery.

Comment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/qCRBwrc.png) is what I am currently trying to do. Choices change depending on selection.

Comment: Okay, I made the updates, hopefully that helps it get closer to what you're looking for.